# Android: How to parse JSON file with Gson Library

Tags: android

I have some code to parse my json file in the raw folder. I am encountering the problem that the method `parse_SSID(ssid)` is not being called and I am getting at the moment 0 in the xml file?!

I am getting result for the ssid variable. Since the mapping for this variable is in the JSON file, I have to parse it to get the route_number value of it.

this is just a part of a method.

```
if (updatedResults.size() > 0) {
    String ssid = deliverBestAccessPoint(updatedResults);
    //retrieve data from json String and parse it.
    int route_number = parse_SSID(ssid); // here I am getting in the xml file 0 and the cursor is not being jumped to the "parse_SSID" method.
    textWifi.setText(String.valueOf(route_number));
}
```

parse_SSID method:

```
private int parse_SSID(String ssid) {
            int route_number=0; 
     InputStream raw =  getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ssid_number);
         Reader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(raw));
         Gson gson = new Gson();            
         WiFiJSONList obj = gson.fromJson(rd, WiFiJSONList.class);
        // Now iterate through the list
        List<WifiJSON> wifijson = obj.getWifiList();
        Iterator iterator = wifijson.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            WifiJSON wifielement = (WifiJSON) iterator.next();
            String ssid_name = wifielement.getSsid();

             if(ssid_name.equals(ssid)){
             route_number = wifielement.getRoute_number();
             }
        }   
        return route_number;

    }
```

WiFiJSONList class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WiFiJSONList {
    private ArrayList<WifiJSON> data;

    public ArrayList<WifiJSON> getWifiList() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setWifiList(ArrayList<WifiJSON> wifiList) {
        this.data = wifiList;
    }
}
```

WifiJSON class:

```
 public class WifiJSON {
        private String ssid;
        private int route_number;

        public WifiJSON(String ssid, int route_number) {
            this.ssid = ssid;
            this.route_number = route_number;

        }

        public String getSsid() {
            return ssid;
        }

        private void setSsid(String ssid) {
            this.ssid = ssid;
        }

        public int getRoute_number() {
            return route_number;
        }

        private void setRoute_number(int route_number) {
            this.route_number = route_number;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "WifiJSON [ssid=" + ssid + ", route_number=" + route_number
                    + "]";
        }


    }
```

ssid_number.txt:

```
     {
    "data": [
        {
            "ssid": "KD Privat",
            "route_number": 1
        },
        {
            "ssid": "KD WLAN Hotspot",
            "route_number": 4
        },
        {
            "ssid": "FR WLAN",
            "route_number": 6
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `WiFiJSONList` and `WifiJSON` classes as well. I've tried your code quickly and it works correctly, so the problem is not in the `parse_SSID` but somewhere else.

Comment: @igor: I have added them.

Comment: can it be up to the Gson libraray? but I have already included it

Comment: Are you sure that `deliverBestAccessPoint()` is returning a valid SSID String?  Also, do you have errors in the logs?

Comment: the error was the spell in the JSON file :) I had "KD WLAN Hotspot" correct--> "KD WLAN Hotspot+" with +